# Are compactly supported functions in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n)$ also in $W_0^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n)$? See for proof?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

The question is stated clearly in the title. On the one hand, it seems obvious (and I give an argument below). On the other hand, after a quick search I haven't been able to find the statement anywhere (statements of this kind mostly focus on trace 0 functions on a domain with Lipschitz boundary), so I worry that the statement may be wrong and that I may be missing something in my argument. The argument is as follows:

Suppose $u\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n)$ is a compactly supported function. Let $\omega$ be a mollifier, write $\omega_m(x):=m^n\omega(mx)$ for each $x\in\mathbb R^n$, and define $u_m:=u*\omega_m$. Since $u,\omega_m$ are compactly supported, then so is each $u_m$. Thus $\{u_m\}\subset C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$. Moreover, $Du_m=(Du)*w_m$, so that $Du_m\rightarrow Du$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore,

$$
u_m\longrightarrow u\quad\text{in }W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n)~~\text{as }m\rightarrow\infty
$$
which implies the desired result.

Comment: In fact, you have $W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n) = W_0^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: Yes, it's true. And something (slightly?) more general holds: if $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open, $l \in \mathbb{N}$, $p \in [1,\infty[$ and $f \in W^{l,p} (\Omega)$ with $\text{supp} \, f$ compact in $\Omega$, then $f \in W_0 ^{l,p} (\Omega)$.

Comment: Thank you for your input Dedalus.